# Can we have 2 'extension_dir' in php.ini?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php.ini, php

When I installed pdo-pgsql, the extension was installed into `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/` and thus not automatically loaded. In `php.ini`, I have `extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626"` already defined.

**Snippet of `php.ini`**

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626"
zend_extension = "/usr/local/IonCube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so"
zend_extension = "/usr/local/Zend/lib/Guard-5.5.0/php-5.3.x/ZendGuardLoader.so"
extension = "eaccelerator.so"
extension = "pdo.so"
extension = "pdo_pgsql.so"
extension = "pdo_sqlite.so"
extension = "sqlite.so"
extension = "pdo_mysql.so"
```

**Modified to work**

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626"
extension_dir = "/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626"
zend_extension = "/usr/local/IonCube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so"
zend_extension = "/usr/local/Zend/lib/Guard-5.5.0/php-5.3.x/ZendGuardLoader.so"
extension = "eaccelerator.so"
extension = "pdo.so"
extension = "pdo_pgsql.so"
extension = "pdo_sqlite.so"
extension = "sqlite.so"
extension = "pdo_mysql.so"
```

1. Why did PECL install pdo-pgsql into the 2nd extension directory and not the first?
2. Is it recommended to have 2 `extension_dir` as shown in the 2nd code snippet above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Because it is the default location when installing via `pecl
   install`, while if you compile PHP from source, the extension path
   should be `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626`.
2. As far as I know, PHP doesn't support multiple `extension_dir`, it
   only pick the last one. Just type `php -i | grep eaccelerator` to see what
   happens.

The workaround is copy the extensions to the right path.

Comment: or make symlinks...

Comment: Is this how I should make the symlinks? : `ln -s /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626 /usr/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626`

Comment: It should be: `ln -s /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626 /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626`. But rename it first: `mv /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626 /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626.bak`.

Comment: Why would you renname it first?

Comment: what happens if you link to a existing directory?